# Do browsers support JavaScript Promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm confused about what I'm seeing online. If I want to use Javascript promises instead of callbacks do I need to be concerned that browsers don't support it?

Thanks.

Comment: As always, it depends on what browsers you want it to work in. http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises

Comment: Also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise#Browser_compatibility

Comment: thanks. I actually saw those links but I thought I was missing something like ie11 only doesn't support certain parts of promises...

Comment: you don't need a transpiler for promises

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see in [can i use promises](http://caniuse.com/#feat=promises), the promises are not supported on IE and some older browsers.

You have many possibilities [to determine if a promise is supported by the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516959/how-to-determine-if-a-promise-is-supported-by-the-browser).

You can also read [how do you use es6 promises today on frontend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39165273/how-do-you-use-es6-promises-today-on-frontend).